# Office-js Word addin, Grabbing document Text

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

In my code below, I am attempting to grab the current documents text, set it to a variable and then use that variable in a call. My promise may not be formatted correctly but essentially the getScanResult() function uses the docBodyText variable that I set in handleClickRun(). Everytime I call it the variable is empty. Any idea as to why the document text is not being captured correctly?

```
const [docBodyText, setDocBodyText] = useState('');
const handleClickRun = async () => {
        return Word.run(async (context: Word.RequestContext) => {
            const docBody = context.document.body;
            docBody.load("text");
            await context.sync();
            setDocBodyText(docBody.text);
            await context.sync();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    };

const handleScanResults = () => {
        new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            await handleClickRun();
            await getScanResult();
            resolve('Completed')
    })};
```

I have tried using the docs and looking for other examples but have not seen any other use cases. The docs I am using is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=word-js-preview) Perhaps I can be pointed to the correct method.

I have also tried making a variable of just plain text and passing it to my api call and it works perfectly fine, so it is not a call issue.

Comment: Please clarify. If you set a break point on the line `setDocBodyText(docBody.text);`, what is the value of `docBody.text` at that point?

Comment: @RickKirkham
Thank you for responding!
When I set a breakpoint there, it is never hit.
I am testing it via webview as I do not know how to hit the breakpoint when executing it in word. Does the Word.run even execute in a web browser? Is there a way to debug while executing the addin in word? Or is there a better way to test this?

Comment: @RickKirkham after testing it again it seems like it is not grabbing the text in the document at all. Is there another way of grabbing all of the text within the document?

Comment: Office.js APIs, like Word.run, only execute in the context of an Office application, like Word. If you open the add-in in a browser window, the Office.js cannot initialize and the Office APIs can't execute. For information about debugging add-ins, start at: [Overview of debugging add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview).